# outlook 2007 - Edit the html?

Tags: html, outlook-2007

I have outlook 2007, and want to edit the html of it. I see under options that HTML is set, then as the body I type `<b>test</b>`, when i send it, and recieve, it still looks like `<b>test</b>` and not **test**. I need it to be bold. (well i know there is an option for making it bold, but I want to find the right way of doing this so I can apply it to other things)

Also I tried exporting as html, then changing the html in it, but I don't know how to open it in outlook again.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

There is an add-on tool to edit HTML directly on Outlook 2010. In 2007, there is a tweak to edit it. See https://superuser.com/questions/536275/how-can-i-edit-the-html-source-code-of-an-email-in-outlook-2010-without-any-add